# facebook graph api, checkins, were_here_count and posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hello I'm learning facebook graph api to research how to using the landmark information to record the city's people or traffic flowing.

I have some question for landmark and fans page.

1. When I noticed a landmark or fans page have got a new checkin, but the data retrieved from Graph Api Explorer has not been changed, and the checkins number is different to the result showed on the fans page very much, does facebook really use the checkin column?
2. What is were_here_count column? It different to checkins column?
3. When I search the Graph API document, I saw a sentence

> "NOTE: Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating
>   a Post with a location attached."

Does it mean that when someone checkin on the landmark, his/her checkins record will be recognized an post object, so that the checkins column has no meaning?

thx!